# Why nam.exe doesn't work in the cygwin without startX?

Tags: cygwin, simulation, ns2

I'm trying to use **NS2** but when I try to use *nam.exe* it'd not work! So is there other way to use *nam.exe* whitout using **startX** in **CygWin**?

thank you

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

``nam´´ is a GUI application (for X), and as such it requires X.

``nam´´ is using some X libraries:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/bin/nam
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0xb76b2000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0xb7564000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0xb7548000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb7543000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb744f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i686/libm.so.6 (0xb7402000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb73e4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/libc.so.6 (0xb721a000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0xb71f7000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76ec000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0xb71f3000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb71ec000)
```

Comment: This was great answer, Thanks.